# How can I use a SortedList with a RecyclerView to sort different parameters?

Tags: android, list, sorting, android-appcompat, sortedlist

I have a `model` with a `rank` and `name` parameters.

The use can choose to sort by rank or by name, so what I did was put a flag inside the SortedList's `compare` method, like this:

```
if (sortByRank) {
    return o1.getRank() > o2.getRank() ? LESS_THAN :
        (o1.getRank() == o2.getRank() ? EQUALS : GREATER_THAN);
}

return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
```

And then in my adapter I have a method to set the sort parameter:

```
public void sortByRank(boolean sort) {
    if (sort) {
        sortByRank = true;
    } else {
        sortByRank = false;
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I thought `notifyDatasetChanged` would prompt the `compare` method, but it doesn't. Any ideas on how to update all at once?

Answer (score 0):

SortedList sorts elements when you add any. So if you write your compare function like that, you will sort your last element by rank or by name. So overall sorting wont make any sense to you.

There is no method for "do sorting again" in SortedList. You change the data adapter for making dynamic sorting happen.

```
recyclerView.swapAdapter(newAdapter, false);`
```

And if you have stable id's in your adapter, you will get a nice animation. Because swapAdapter() helps RecyclerView to re-use view holders.